# How we compare two strings and get the difference between them in java

Tags: java

I want to compare two strings and get the difference between them...like
1st string: "This version has keypad system"
2nd String: "This version has touchpad system"

Difference will be: "key" and "touch"

Comment: What is a difference exactly? What should be the output for "abaca" and "abda", for example?

Answer (score 0):

Put words of the 1st string in Set, then check which words in 2nd string are present in the Set.